# Visual Studio Team Services ***NO_CI*** Not working with Bitbucket and Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, bitbucket, azure-devops

I am trying to setup a continuous integration and deployment for my Xcode project that is in Bitbucket, using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).

In my build script for VSTS, that is triggered by changes to the 'develop' branch, I do the following steps:

1. Pull the 'develop' branch from BitBucket. (Using Get sources)
2. Increment the build number in my project's plist file. (Using Fastlane)
3. Commit and tag the build number change back to the 'develop' branch. (Using Fastlane)
4. Build the project and create the .ipa file. (Using the Apple AppStore extension for VSTS)
5. Upload the .ipa file for the release script. (Using Publish Artifact)

In my release script for VSTS, that is triggered by a successful build, I do the following steps:

1. Download the .ipa file.
2. Publish .ipa to iTunes Connect/TestFlight (Using the Apple AppStore extension for VSTS)

When I commit the version change on the 'develop' branch, it triggers another build in VSTS. Looking through the documentation I find this:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/scripts/git-commands#how-do-i-avoid-triggering-a-ci-build-when-the-script-pushes

> **How do I avoid triggering a CI build when the script pushes?**
>
> Add ***NO_CI*** to your commit message. For example, git merge origin/features/hello-world -m "Merge to master ***NO_CI***"

I tried the commit messages:

" ***NO_CI*** VSTS build v1.0.0 (1) "

and

" VSTS build v1.0.0 (1) ***NO_CI*** "

Neither of them worked, the build was still triggered.

**So my question is:**
How can I use VSTS, Bitbucket, and an iOS project to setup continuous integration and deployment including version number changes in my Xcode project?

Answer (score 1):

For now, you can use VSTS to CI build and CD deploy for your bitbucket repo. But you can’t use `***NO_CI***` to avoid CI build for bitbucket repo.

I posted an user voice [Avoid CI build for Bitbucket repo](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/20155861-avoid-ci-build-for-bitbucket-repo), you can vote and follow up.

The way to add a CI build for your bitbucket repo: build definition -> get source step -> select remote repo -> new service connection or the connection your created -> input your bitbucket repo URL and credential -> OK -> add other task for your needs -> save. Now when new changed are pushed to your bitbucket repo, the build will be triggered.